# NPV of Interest Rate Swap not coming to be 0 at initiation

Tags: programming, quantlib, interest-rate-swap

I am using the iPython notebook published by Gouthaman Balaraman at [http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/interest-rate-swap-quantlib-python.html][1]

This is to value the Interest Rate Swap. I am intrigued that the NPV of swap is not 0 even if we were to be using the same quotes using which the discount curve (and same forecast curve) was constructed. Could someone kindly help me in understanding in what would it take to get the NPV = 0 in the example?

Comment: Why not ask Mr. Balaraman? Looking at his page, one of the outputs from QL is a different rate for the fixed leg that would cause the swap to have 0 pv.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. How do I ask him?

Comment: His page says: "If you found these posts useful, please take a minute by providing some feedback", with the word "feedback" being a link. Your browser probably indicates this by displaying the word "feedback" in a different color.

Comment: I actually tried on some the other examples as well as given in the cookbook by Luigi and Gouthaman, still the same. NPV is never equal to 0. I think there is a key piece that I am missing. If anyone could help out, much appreciated.

Comment: I never used quantlib but if you simply hard code a fixed rate, it will unlikely be zero. Seems the code outputs a Fair Spread and Fair Rate though. Have you tried these as inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fair rate calculated in the above example is the rate to be used for fixed rate leg to yield 0 NPV. You would need to reconstruct the swap with the float leg as is but a fixed leg with fair rate from above. That should yield a 0 NPV for the swap.